# How to Display a "New Item Alert Window" in Outlook Whenever I am in To of Any Emails Irrecpective of the Other Rules Getting Applied

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

I need to create a rule, so that whenever someone adds me in "To" of any emails, Outlook should open a New Item Alert Window (Not the Desktop Alert) and I can open the email right from there. There could be other rules getting applied which might be moving the email to another folder.

Currently, when I setup this kind of rule, it shows the alert window, but sometimes, when I try to open the email, it says the message is not available anymore. While it is present in the folder as per the other applied rule. Can we prioritize the rules so that the alert window can open the email even if it is moved to another folder?

Comment: `someone adds me in "To" of any emails` ... that's `when new email arrives`

Answer (score 0):

> Can we prioritize the rules so that the alert window can open the email even if it is moved to another folder?

1. Make sure the new item alert window rule is the last one so that it will apply lastly.
2. Also ensure the option **stop processing more rules** is NOT used in the other rules, otherwise subsequent rules will be ignored, even if they apply to the message.

For example, I have a rule that moves mails to another folder and I put it in a higher order so that it would be apply first:

[image]

For the rule which triggers the New item alert window, I moved it to down to the last one, so that it would be applied lastly:

[image]

Based on my test, the new item alert window can work as expected:
[image]